# Android - Setting date to RelevantDate with an CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

Let me just give an example of the requirements I am trying to fulfill. (Sorry if it's kind of a dumb question but my brain is a little fried right now and I'm working on this by myself)

I have a CursorAdapter (w/ SQLite on the backend) that I am using for my ListView to display content. One of the fields in the list item that I am displaying is the date the item was added to the Listview. So...

**CASE:**

*If today was December 31st, 2013 and I just created a list item I would like it to display "**Today**". On January 1st, 2014 I would like the date to change to "**Yesterday**". And finally, on January 2nd, 2014 I would like the date to change to "**12/31/2013**".*

What is the simple or most elegant way of fulfilling these requirements? I don't want to be constantly checking my whole listview for dates and be mean to the CPU. Any ideas on the best practice of saving the date would also be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it working... I use this method in the activity where my listview is and call it every onCreate, onStart, and onResume.

```
 public void setRelevantDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US); 
    Date date = new Date();
    String current_date = year.format(date);
    String db_day_after_creation_date;



  //check dates created, sub "today" or "yesterday"
    for(SoundData s: app.unsent_recordings){
        Log.e("soundData date flag",String.valueOf(s.isAfter_Day_two()));
        Log.e("soundData date buffer",s.getDate_buffer());
        Log.e("soundData date created",s.getDate_created());

        if (!s.isAfter_Day_two()){ //if we are two days after the creation then we can skip all the checks for this item because
                                    // it has already been set back to the initial MM/dd/yyyy date format
        String sql_date = s.getDate_buffer();
        String db_date = sql_date.substring(0,10);
        String db_time = sql_date.substring(11);

        //find the day after creation date
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(db_date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        db_day_after_creation_date = sdf.format(c.getTime());


        if (db_date.equals(current_date)){
                   s.setDate_created("Today, "+db_time);
                   app.update_Recording_DateCreated(s.getId(),"Today, "+db_time, s.getDate_buffer(), String.valueOf(s.isAfter_Day_two()));  //dateCreated = today, TIME
        }
        else if(current_date.equals(db_day_after_creation_date)){                       // basically if the current date is equal to the day after the db_created date
                   s.setDate_created("Yesterday, "+db_time);
                                                                //we can say that it was created yesterday
                   app.update_Recording_DateCreated(s.getId(),"Yesterday, "+db_time, s.getDate_buffer(), String.valueOf(s.isAfter_Day_two()));  

        }
        else{
                s.setDate_created(sql_date);
                                                        //Otherwise use normal date
                app.update_Recording_DateCreated(s.getId(),sql_date,s.getDate_buffer(), String.valueOf(s.isAfter_Day_two()));   //dateCreated = dateBuffer

        }

            app.mCursor = app.db.getCursor();
            app.rec_adapter.changeCursor(app.mCursor);
            app.rec_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                             //Update cursor, notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```